# Calculating mean value for every month in a timeseries using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple time series:

```
Month
1980-01-01    28.687977
1980-02-01    27.928480
1980-03-01    32.526912
1980-04-01    37.376463
1980-05-01    37.920970
1980-06-01    42.673177
1980-07-01    44.158804
1980-08-01    52.697249
1980-09-01    47.518417
1980-10-01    38.845849
1980-11-01    31.685959
1980-12-01    26.267851
1981-01-01    28.861739
1981-02-01    28.600699
1981-03-01    32.664966
1981-04-01    39.000000
1981-05-01    39.484174
1981-06-01    42.755117
1981-07-01    46.658333
1981-08-01    56.062465
...
```

Where 1980-02-01 is 1st February 1980.

It goes on and on.

I would like to get a mean value for every month.

`Month` is an `DatetimeIndex` so I could for example do `df['1980'].mean()` to get the mean for a given year. What I need is the mean for each month but I don't know how to specify selector for month `df['???'].mean()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) and aggregate `mean`:

```
s.groupby(s.index.month).mean()
```